# Memory Management in iOS with ARC Enabled

Tags: memory-management

I Have the below code in xxxviewcontroller.m and temp is  UIImageView instance variable in .h file.

```
- (IBAction)buttonclicked:(id)sender {

  for (int i=0; i<=100; i++)
   {
     temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"]];
  }
```

}

So for each iteration in for loop we should have one dangling pointer, since temp is reassigned and the previous ins.In instruments i see memory raise when the button is clicked but it soon comes back to what it was after the end of the method. This view controller is the firstviewcontroller on the navigation controller stack. I want to check if insturments will show this in leaks. but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

In ARC, if you assign a new value to an existing varialbe, it points to new value and previous value (which has no owner now) is collected and freed.
For example:
if we have a `self.textField.text = @"Rayman"`

[image]

If we assign a new value to it as `self.textField.text = @"Mister Dark"`. Previouw value i.e `@"Rayman"` is freed at that moment. This is why you see that at the end of method, you see the memory which was allocated is freed as those memory has no owner.

[image]

[Images taken from [here]](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1)

Comment: Thanks for the response. but i still have few queries , why is the instruments showing the memory being released after the for loop finished. if what your saying is right,then there should be no increase in memory when the for loop is in progress. It is not clear when we have count of 100 in for loop but when i put 100000 in for loop count the memory stress is clearly visible.